# redirect_to with anchor and tab

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use redirect to send the user back to the tab they were just at, Redemptions, and use an anchor to bring this tab into view. To clarify I want the second, or "last" tab to open upon redirect. The question is how do I make this happen?

```
class CustomerRewardRedemptionsController
  def fulfill
    redirect_to admin_customer_rewards_path
  end
end
```

Could be redirect_to :back

```
<div class="tab-nav">
  <ul class="tabs tabs-large">
    <li class="active"><a href="#points-leveling" data-toggle="tab">Points Leveling</a><b class="triangle"></b></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="#leaderboard" data-toggle="tab">Redemptions</a></li>
  </ul> 
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="leaderboard">
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to 'Mark Fulfilled', fulfill_admin_customer_reward_redemptions_path(customer_reward_redemption_id: redemption.id), method: :put, class: 'btn', 'data-confirm' => 'Mark the redemption fulfilled?' %></td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

**Update**: The anchor works, tab still opens the default and not the "last".

```
redirect_to admin_customer_rewards_path + "#rewards"
```

This plus adding the below anchor one level up above the "tab-nav"

```
<div class="col-md-12"><a name="rewards"></a>
  <div class="tab-nav">
    <ul class="tabs tabs-large">
      <li class="active"><a href="#points-leveling" data-toggle="tab">Points Leveling</a><b class="triangle"></b></li>
      <li class="last"><a href="#leaderboard" data-toggle="tab">Redemptions</a></li>
    </ul> 
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="leaderboard">
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to 'Mark Fulfilled', fulfill_admin_customer_reward_redemptions_path(customer_reward_redemption_id: redemption.id), method: :put, class: 'btn', 'data-confirm' => 'Mark the redemption fulfilled?' %></td>
    </tr>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Solution**: Found this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/18370966/3889146

```
<div class="col-md-12"><a name="rewards"></a>
  <div class="tab-nav">
    <ul class="tabs tabs-large">
      <li class="<%= @tab == "rewards" ? "active" : "" %>"><a href="#points-leveling" data-toggle="tab">Points Leveling</a><b class="<%= @tab == "rewards" ? "triangle" : "" %>"></b></li>
      <li class="last <%= @tab == "rewards" ? "" : "active" %>"><a href="#leaderboard" data-toggle="tab">Redemptions</a><b class="<%= @tab == "rewards" ? "" : "triangle" %>"></b></li>
    </ul> 
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane <%= @tab == "rewards" ? "active" : "" %>" id="points-leveling">
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane <%= @tab == "rewards" ? "" : "active" %>" id="leaderboard">
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to 'Mark Fulfilled', fulfill_admin_customer_reward_redemptions_path(customer_reward_redemption_id: redemption.id), method: :put, class: 'btn', 'data-confirm' => 'Mark the redemption fulfilled?' %></td>
    </tr>
  </div>
</div>
```

Solved the redirect_to with the above answer and https://stackoverflow.com/a/757937/3889146

```
class CustomerRewardRedemptionsController
  def index
    @tab = params[:tab]
  end

  def fulfill
    redirect_to admin_customer_rewards_path(tab: "rewards") + "#rewards"
  end
end
```

Hope this helps others!

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question. I got the anchor working but still want the Redemptions tab to open after redirect.